# Creating app for Excel 2003 with Excel 2007

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, excel-2003

I'm writing .Net desktop application to create reports in Excel 2003, but I have only Excel 2007, and have no license of Excel 2003. This is my problem, because when I launch this app on client’s computer (Excel 2003), I have error (SystemNullReferenceException).

I know reasons of this exception (different versions of Excel), but I don't know any solution.

Comment: You would need excel 2003 APIs to develop app for Excel 2003.

Comment: Can I get excel APIs without Excel installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it will work but you can consider installing excel viewer on the client's computer. It appears to be a free download of about 75 MB.